# Sorting and Comparing Object with BubbleSort

Tags: java, sorting, object, compare

I have problem with my Java program. Can all of you help me..
This is the program.
**Introduction**
On the website "MukaBuku", every user has the following property:

1. Name, the name of the user
2. Posts, a number of works published post
3. Friends, a number of existing friends

Of the property, Mr. C want some sort DOWN as follows:

1. Compare user based on the large number of existing Friends. If there are two
   users who have the same number of Friends who then continue the process of sorting the points 2
2. Compare user based on the number of Posts that exist. If there are two users who
   have the same amount Posts sorting process then proceed to point 3
3. Last is to compare two users based on their name in a letter of the alphabet.

**Input Format**
Input consists of N +1 lines. On the line to - 1 represents the number of users that exist in
website "MukaBuku", where 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000. Then in row - 2 to row
**Output Format**
The output consists of N lines.

example
input :

```
6 
Budi 13 14,
Andi 90 87,
Fawwaz 39 109, 
Bayu 41 9, 
Ani 77 77, 
Ano 77 77,
```

output :

```
Total Sorting : 8 
Fawwaz 109 39 
Andi 87 90 
Ano 77 77 
Ani 77 77 
Budi 14 13 
Bayu 9 41
```

Comment: I suggest you start with a simple program and add functionality to make it do more until it does the whole thing.  I wouldn't over think it.

Comment: Too much of theory. Add code snippets which you think are causing the problem

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the above post says, have your MukabuMember implement the `Comparable<MukabuMember>`  interface. then override `public int compareTo(MukabuMember m)` with the comparison process that you explained.

Once this is done, you can call Arrays.sort(yourlist), and it will be sorted your way.

Comment: Don't you think that implementing a bubble sort doesn't imply using `Comparable` and `Collections.sort()` especially as they are based on merge sort? Obviously it's homework so you are doing a bad favour giving an answer of this kind. A mental -1 for you.

Comment: true, he should use the overridden compareTo in his home made BubbleSort, but not Arrays.sort

Answer (score 1):

Have a class(say MukabuMember) with all the propreties that u've mentioned as fields. Now have a main class and create N objects for the MukabuMember class. Create a list with MukabuMember class as parameter. Use an iterator to traverse through the list for sorting. Instead of a single compare stmt, you need three compares (in a nested if fashion) to sort according to ur requirements. This should do enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Create a class called MukabukuMember that has the fields **name**, **numberOfPosts** **numberOfFriends**
2. Make this class implement the **Comparable** interface.This interface has a single method **compareTo** where-in you can write all the comparison logic.
3. Mkae sure you also override the **equals** and **hashCode** method in the MukabukuMember class.**A special care you need to take is to ensure that the logic to determine that two MukabukuMember classes are equal are the same in both the compareTo and equals**

Once you are done with the above three steps, you can either store these objects within a **List** and iterate over it. Within each iteration you can simply then test two objects of the **MukabukuMember** class say **obj1** and **obj2** as follows:

- **obj1.compareTo(obj2)** - Returns **1** if obj1 > obj2; **0** if obj1 == obj2 and **-1** if obj1 < ob
- **obj1.equals(obj2)** - Returns true if **obj1 == obj2**

Comment: I'm sorry, but in my project/work i forbidden to use Comparable interface. Just using Bubblesort..